How to re-order bars in statplot - graph bar?
I am using this Stata code to plot percent agreements on some conspiracy theory variables. I successfully plot them the way I wanted using statplot but I could not sort the graph bars in a descending way to make it look neater. I want the bars in this graph to be sorted by the percent agreement on Republicans. So illegal voting would be the first and "fraud Republicans" would be the last variable. So I want them to be sorted by conspiracy theory but ordered in a way so that the percent agreements of Republicans start from the highest and go lower as you go down.
enter image description here
gen total_republican = non1 + non2 + non3 + non4 + dem1 + dem2 + dem3 + dem4 + rep1 + rep2 + rep3 + rep4 if demo==0

statplot non1 non2 non3 non4 dem1 dem2 dem3 dem4 rep1 rep2 rep3 rep4 , ///
over(democrat, sort(total_republican) descending) recast(bar) horizontal asyvars bar(1, color(stc2)) bar(2, color(stc1))    

I got a good shape of bars, but I need to sort them as described above.

statplot is from SSC, as you are asked to explain (see stata tag wiki).
There is no MRE here (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
Your graph shows proportions, not percentages.
That said, just firing up summarize to calculate the means is short work. For an automated solution, see also sortmean from SSC.
https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1707627-sorting-variables-meaning-variable-names-by-their-means explains.
To install that directly, navigate to a suitable directory or folder and
ssc copy sortmean.ado 
ssc copy sortmean.sthlp 

Here is a reproducible example, provided that Stata can see the statplot and sortmean files.
webuse nlswork, clear

statplot nev_mar collgrad not_smsa c_city south union, over(msp)

sortmean nev_mar collgrad not_smsa c_city south union if msp == 1

statplot `sortlist', over(msp)

